# SQL OrderBy Clause Not Working with max alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
Select tableA.*,  max(`queue_position`) AS `product_advertisements.queue_position` 
from tableA join tableB
group by tableA.attribute
order by `product_advertisements.queue_position` ASC
```

When the query runs, its not actually sorting by the queue position,

This is my return https://gyazo.com/471749b349d64e94707b9452d4b25417,
This is the expected output, https://gyazo.com/e8c92b2898a404781c9de095f1146143

Does it have something to do with ordering by the joined attribute? Why is my order by clause being ignored completely

Comment: use  max(`queue_position`) in order by instead of  `product_advertisements.queue_position`

Comment: You're actually a genius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know the name of all columns, but I guess there is a column with the same name "product_advertisements.queue_position", and you do not want to order by it. Instead, you want to order by MAX(queue_position)

Try these 2 options:

1. Use the MAX column as the first column, and "ORDER BY 1", it would apply the order clause to the first column.

   Select max(queue_position) AS product_advertisements.queue_position, tableA.*
   from tableA join tableB
   group by tableA.attribute
   order by 1 ASC;
2. Use "max(queue_position)" in the ORDER CLAUSE

   Select tableA.*,  max(queue_position) AS product_advertisements.queue_position
   from tableA join tableB
   group by tableA.attribute
   order by max(queue_position) ASC

Anyway, why do you select all columns (tableA.*), but group only by one? MySQL accepts it, but in other Databases it is not allowed.